# Whats is this metric class?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

Show that
$d_{1}(f, g) := \int_{0}^{1}|f − g|$
defines a metric on the class $C([0, 1])$ of continuous functions $f : [0, 1] → R$

I got an anwser for this question by showing that $|f − g| \ge 0$ and that $|f − g|=|g − f|$ and then also the triangle inequality which shows it is a metric then I added the integral sign into it.

I was just wondering if this was the correct way to go about this?
Also I don't understand what the metric class $C([0, 1])$ is and how this affects the outcome in anyway?

Comment: $C([0,1])$ is the class of all continuous functions on $[0,1]$. I'm not sure what you mean by "metric class".

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know if it was specially for metric spaces so I didn't know what to call it as I've never seen it before hence the "metric class".

Comment: Suppose $h:[0,1]\to [0,\infty)$ is continuous and $h(v)>0$ for some $v\in [0,1]$ then there exists $r>0$ such that $h(x)\geq h(v)/2$ for all $x\in [-r+v, r+v]\cap [0,1].$  Since $J=[-r+v,r+v]\cap [0,1]$ is  an interval whose length $L$ is positive, we have $\int_0^1h(x)dx\geq \int_Jh(x)dx\geq  Lh(v)/2>0.$....  So for $f, g \in C[0,1]$ let  $h=|f-g|$, and  we obtain $f\ne g\implies d_1(f,g)>0.$ .... And your idea for the triangle inequality works fine.